# gtk image suddenly do not refresh without any errors or warnings

Tags: c++, ubuntu, gtk, gtkmm

I develop a tool to capture image from a camera and show the captured image in a window. The GUI window is based on GTK 2.4. At begin, the tool is running correctedly, and the image is captured from camera and showed on the window in real-time. After a while, the image suddenly do not refresh any more on the window, but it's still captured from the camera. There is no errors or warnings. Anyone has ever encountered such a case? Thank you.

Ubuntu 18.04, GTK 2.4

```
  // loop to call the following code to refresh the image on the window
  pixbuf_ = Gdk::Pixbuf::create_from_data(
      final_img_buf_.data, Gdk::COLORSPACE_RGB, false, 8, final_img_buf_.cols,
      final_img_buf_.rows, static_cast<int>(final_img_buf_.step));
  gtk_image_.set(pixbuf_);
```

---

Edit at 2019-02-27
Thanks for all your replies. I have upgraded GTK to GTK+ 3, but this still appears.

```
  // loop to call the following code to refresh the image on the window
  pixbuf_ = Gdk::Pixbuf::create_from_data(
      final_img_buf_.data, Gdk::COLORSPACE_RGB, false, 8, final_img_buf_.cols,
      final_img_buf_.rows, static_cast<int>(final_img_buf_.step));
  // ensure the image is normally updating
  //std::this_thread::sleep_for (std::chrono::milliseconds(30));
  gtk_image_.set(pixbuf_);
  Glib::RefPtr<Gdk::Pixbuf> pixbuf = gtk_image_.get_pixbuf();
  std::string filename = std::string("./debug/") + std::to_string(CurTimestampMicrosecond()) + std::string(".jpg");
  pixbuf->save(filename, "jpeg");
```

Afther running a while, the window does not refresh image any more, but the image is still saved correctedly.

Edit at 2019-02-28

```
// The initialization code
gtk_main_.reset(new Gtk::Main(argc, argv));
ctrl_window_.reset(new CtrlWindow(screen, ctrl_rect)); // inherited from Gtk::Window
thread_ = std::thread([this]() {
  Gtk::Main::run(*ctrl_window_);
}
```

Comment: This problem can be avoided as follows, but I still do not know why.        
pixbuf_ = Gdk::Pixbuf::create_from_data(
      final_img_buf_.data, Gdk::COLORSPACE_RGB, false, 8, final_img_buf_.cols,
      final_img_buf_.rows, static_cast<int>(final_img_buf_.step));
  // sleep 20ms to ensure the image is normally updating
  std::this_thread::sleep_for (std::chrono::milliseconds(20));
  gtk_image_.set(pixbuf_);

Comment: Make sure you're not leaking some image memory. Try to reuse the same pixel buffer if possible as the image will always have the same characteristics. And BTW, GTK+ 2.4 is almost 15 years old. If you're not maintaining an old and big codebase, you should really switch to GTK+ 3.

Comment: The way you're looping is also important, are you using threads, or GSources like g_idle_add or g_timeout?

Comment: @liberforce Thanks for your reply. I have updated my problem. Do you have other advices?

Comment: You didn't answer my question. How do you call that code? Using threads, or GSources like g_idle_add or g_timeout?

Comment: I use a std::thread. In this thread, the image is captured from camera and displayed using the above code periodically, about 10~20 images per second. Thank you.

Comment: You probably should be using GStreamer for this kind of use, as otherwise you'll need to handle synchronization yourself. I once tried something similar, the culprit what the filesystem: I was writing too much data and the kernel couln't keep up. Have you tried removing the `pixbuf-save()` call? You should also check that you don't leak memory.

Comment: Another thing is that you can't call any GTK+ function from your thread. Instead, you have to pass the data to the main thread used by GTK+ through `g_idle_add` or similar function. Only that thread can safely access GTK+ objects, like what you are doing to set a `GtkImage`'s pixbuf.

Comment: @liberforce Very thanks for your kind reply. I add the following code in main thread instead of calling the update function in another thread. Glib::signal_timeout().connect(sigc::mem_fun(*this, &ImageWindow::UpdateGtkImage), 40); **It works so far.** I will continue to test the stability, and report the test result later.  Thank you again.

Comment: Be aware that `g_signal_timeout` doesn't handle synchronization. Depending on the machine's CPU load, the can be big delays, and delays will add up, like a drifting metronome. So if you have a specific framerate to respect, and potentially need to drop frames, you'll probably be better served with GStreamer.

Comment: I used g_signal_idle instead of g_signal_timeout. After about 3 hours running，the window still do not refresh. When I close the window, it says "no responsing". Is the window too busy to process the update event? Do you have any advice to solve this problem?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Looks like both `g_timeout_add` and possibly `g_idle_add` can be delayed due to the processing of other event sources, so is not optimal in contexts requiring precise timing, like drawing an image to a screen before the frame updates. I've noticed using `g_timeout_add` in a 2D graphics context completely freezes the application if it can't load a frame at the fps specified.

`gtk_widget_add_callback()` might be more suited to your needs as it will draw the buffer as quickly as the application can, without hangs, basically doing the messy synchronization for you.

Comment: Thank you. Now I used GLib::Dispatcher to register event and send signal, instead of g_timeout_add or g_idle_add, it works so far, and the load average is lower.